# Compare text of "n" no of dynmically created textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my Code, I allow the user to add dynamically any no of textboxes. and i need to ensure to that the text in all these textboxes are different. How do i go about using Jquery?
Please help me out. Am stuck in this.

Comment: Please provide us what you tried, HTML and jQuery

Comment: supposing user has chosen to create 4 textbox
<input type='text' name='commonname' id='text1'/>
<input type='text' name='commonname' id='text2'/>
<input type='text' name='commonname' id='text3'/>
<input type='text' name='commonname' id='text4'/>
i need to compare all the four values in textbox...ensure all values are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validation try something like

```
var obj = {};
$('input', $ct).each(function(i, v){
    var $this = $(this).removeClass('error');;
    var val = $this.val();
    if(val && obj[val]){
        alert(val + ' exists');
        $this.addClass('error');
    }
    obj[val] = true;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yRkfn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a custom `ID`

<kbd>**[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ejihac/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
var n = 0;
$('#createTextbox').click(function(){ 
  var newTextbox = '<input type="text" id="textbox_'+ (n++) +'"/>';
  $('#area').append( newTextbox );
});


$('#area').on('click', '[id^=textbox_]', function(){
  alert( this.id );
});
```

where `(n++)` will increment the ID of your new textbox, and using `.on` with delegated events you can take care for future actions to retrieve what you need from them.
To bind the click to every new `textbox_*N*` inside a desired `area` element use the **starts with selector `^`** : `[id^=textbox_]` .

http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/append/
http://api.jquery.com/on/